# Java getter setter failing to store value

Tags: java

I'm trying to answer these questions.

1. The New Account option should implement the following:

   - Input client details: name, address, birthday, and contact number
   - Input the initial deposit of not less than PhP5,000
   - Generate a four-digit account number randomly
2. The Balance Inquiry option should implement the following:

   - Input the account number and validate
   - If the account number is valid, display the client name and current 
     balance

I've tried coding the New Account option with setter methods in it and also generates a four-digit number randomly that I can use to input it in the Balance Inquiry option that has getter methods but it displays empty. I tried debugging it and the variables return empty after exiting the if statement.

Class with the main method, displayMainMenu() for the options, newAccount() and fourRandomNumber().

```java
public class ClientUgang { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayMainMenu();
    }

    public static void displayMainMenu() {
        SavingsAccountUgang savingsAccount = new SavingsAccountUgang();

        int option = 0;
        while (option != 7) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("JBank Main Menu");
            System.out.println("[1] New Account");
            System.out.println("[2] Balance Inquiry");
            System.out.println("[3] Deposit");
            System.out.println("[4] Withdraw");
            System.out.println("[5] Client Profile");
            System.out.println("[6] Close Account");
            System.out.println("[7] Exit");
            option = scan.nextInt();

            if (option == 1) {
                newAccount();
            }
            if (option == 2) {
                savingsAccount.balanceInquiry();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void newAccount() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        SavingsAccountUgang savingsAccount = new SavingsAccountUgang();

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        String address = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Birthday: ");
        String birthday = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Contact number: ");
        String contactNumber = scan.nextLine();

        savingsAccount.setAccountName(name);
        savingsAccount.setAddress(address);
        savingsAccount.setBirthday(birthday);
        savingsAccount.setContactNumber(contactNumber);

        int deposit = 0;
        while (deposit < 5000) {
            System.out.print("Initial deposit(not less than Php5000): ");
            deposit = scan.nextInt();
        }
        savingsAccount.setBalance(deposit);

        int fourDigitNumber = fourRandomNumber(1000, 9000);
        savingsAccount.setAccountNo(fourDigitNumber);

        System.out.println("Your Account Number: " + fourDigitNumber);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int fourRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

The Class where my balanceInquiry() method is. My setter and getter method for accountName is in BankAccountUgang class.

```java
public class SavingsAccountUgang extends BankAccountUgang {
    private int accountNo;
    private double balance;

    public SavingsAccountUgang() {
    }

    public int getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }

    public void setAccountNo(int accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    public void balanceInquiry() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int accountNumber = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Account Number: ");
            accountNumber = scan.nextInt());
        } while (accountNumber != getAccountNo());

        System.out.println(getAccountName());
        System.out.println(getBalance());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I expect the setter methods to work so that I can call the getter methods.

```
JBank Main Menu
[1] New Account
[2] Balance Inquiry
[3] Deposit
[4] Withdraw
[5] Client Profile
[6] Close Account
[7] Exit
1
Name: John
Address: World
Birthday: Aug 2019
Contact number: 123 1234
Initial deposit(not less than Php5000): 5000
Your Account Number: 6810

JBank Main Menu
[1] New Account
[2] Balance Inquiry
[3] Deposit
[4] Withdraw
[5] Client Profile
[6] Close Account
[7] Exit
2
Enter Account Number: 6810
Enter Account Number: BUILD STOPPED (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Comment: Because you're referring to two different `SavingsAccountUgang` objects in your code. You create a new one in your `displayMainMenu()` and a 2nd one in your `newAccount()` methods. They do not refer to the same instance and will have different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

To fix that 1 way is below:

1. Return a new saving account from the `newAccount` method, so change the return type to:

```
public static SavingsAccountUgang newAccount() {
    // Your existing code
    return savingsAccount;
}
```

2. Then in your `displayMainMenu()` method save this account if the user enters 1 as an input and later use that instance to show the balance:

```
public static void displayMainMenu() {
    SavingsAccountUgang savingsAccount = null // don't create object here as you are doing
    // Your code
    if (option == 1) {
        savingsAccount = newAccount();
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        if(savingsAccount  == null) {
            // throw exception or whatever you want to do.
        }
        savingsAccount.balanceInquiry();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SavingsAccountUgang` instance in your `newAccount()` method is a local variable and therefore only visible to this method. 
If you want to use it outside your method you have to return or declare it outside of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `setBalance()` method requires an argument type `double`, but you send a type `int`, but it's not a reason for a mistake. Also, you should use `this` in a statement like this one:

```
while (accountNumber != this.getAccountNo());
```

Comment: the `int` variable is implicitly cast to `double` here. That's why it shouldn't be any *technical* problem. And even though I agree with you concerning the `this.` keyword - it's generally not necessary when calling a method. Furthermore, since it is a simple `getter` OP could directly access the variable (with `accountNumber != this.accountNo`) instead of the method call.